# What is the thickness of an A320 radome?

Tags: airbus-a320, airbus, radome

What is the thickness of an A320 radome? This is needed to run some simulations.

Comment: Nomex core material comes in thicknesses from 1/8" to 1".  A radome is probably around 1/2" or maybe 3/4" but you'd need an engineering drawing. Suggest you write to Airbus customer support.

Answer (score 2):

It varies in different part numbers. Yes, Airbus offers a few designs to use. I'm not a structure expert, but I'm pretty sure the main difference is on their material, like Kevlar or Quartz, and how these material distribute (be reminded it's a composite structure).

From a maintenance manual of a few A320 radome designs, the overall thickness on the front face (yes, different area have different thickness) varies from around 7.5 mm to around 9 mm.

Hopefully that helps. And sorry that the exact could not be provided due to the manual is confidential and proprietary.

I'm not sure what kind of simulation you doing, FEA? CFD? Or just flight simulation? If you really want some exact numbers, try ask an airline or Airbus formally for their support.